# Format TextBoxFor database first custom date format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC4 and building a front-end application for a large process which is driven on SQL server - so my EF approach is Database first as all the logic and processing is done there.

I have one entity (Sql Table) which has a date field but it is written as a Decimal(8, 0) and is in this format "yyyyMMdd" (20160623).

Is there a way for me to do a DateTime.TryParseExact and return a Datetime value into TextBoxFor? TryParseExact because the values are 0, valid-date, 99999999.

I tried using a helper method (c# not cshtml) but I get a

> *Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions*

I don't want to fiddle with the model and DisplayFormat annotations as I can expect the database to change and Update Model from Database would overwrite my formatting.

**Edit:**

This would be a temporary solution, but perhaps there would be a better way (and actually using TextBoxFor)

```
@Html.TextBox("DateAdded", nHelpers.YYYYMMDDToShortDateString(Model.DateAdded.ToString), New With {.class = "tBox", .style = "width: 80px"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views\Shared\EditorTemplates, create new partial view called CoreDateToShortDateString. Use this code:

```
@ModelType System.Decimal?
@If Model IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim datum As DateTime
  If DateTime.TryParseExact(Model.Value.ToString, "yyyyMMdd", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, datum) Then
    @Html.TextBox("", datum.ToShortDateString)
  Else
    @Html.TextBox("", Model.Value)
  End If
End If
```

Using:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.DateAdded, "CoreDateToShortDateString")
```